# Embedding and transferring data from table view cell to multiple Uitextfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, search

*I have a search display controller linked with a table view so when the user searches they can select the option they want. After they select the search term they want, the table view cell will need to unpack the data into three separate text fields so i will need to know how to embed this into the table view cell.*

**Here is my code for the search display controller:**

```
@synthesize candyArray;
@synthesize filteredCandyArray;
@synthesize candySearchBar;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Don't show the scope bar or cancel button until editing begins
    [candySearchBar setShowsScopeBar:NO];
    [candySearchBar sizeToFit];

    // Hide the search bar until user scrolls up
    CGRect newBounds = [[self tableView] bounds];
    newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + candySearchBar.bounds.size.height;
    [[self tableView] setBounds:newBounds];

    /*** Sample Data for candyArray ***/

    candyArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Good" name:@"Bath Towel - Kmart"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Good" name:@"Bath Towel - Wallmart"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Good" name:@"Bath Towel - Target"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Better" name:@"Bath Towel - Khols"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Better" name:@"Bath Towel - JCpenny"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Best" name:@"Bath Towel - Dillards"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Best" name:@"Bath Towel - Macy's"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Good" name:@"Hand Towel - Kmart"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Good" name:@"Hand Towel - Wallmart"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"Good" name:@"Hand Towel - Target"][Candy candyOfCategory:@"Best" name:@"Bath Canister - Macy's"], nil];

    // Initialize the filteredCandyArray with a capacity equal to the candyArray's capacity
    filteredCandyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[candyArray count]];

    // Reload the table
    [[self tableView] reloadData];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and return the count from the appropriate array
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [filteredCandyArray count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [candyArray count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Create a new Candy Object
    Candy *candy = nil;

    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and set the Candy object from the appropriate array
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        candy = [filteredCandyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
    else
    {
        candy = [candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[candy name]];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Perform segue to candy detail
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"candyDetail" sender:tableView];
}

#pragma mark - Segue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"candyDetail"] ) {
        UIViewController *candyDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        // In order to manipulate the destination view controller, another check on which table (search or normal) is displayed is needed
        if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[filteredCandyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
            [candyDetailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
        }
        else {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
            [candyDetailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
        }

    }
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


#pragma mark Content Filtering

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.

    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array
    [self.filteredCandyArray removeAllObjects];

    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
    NSArray *tempArray = [candyArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if(![scope isEqualToString:@"All"]) {
        // Further filter the array with the scope
        NSPredicate *scopePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.category contains[c] %@",scope];
        tempArray = [tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:scopePredicate];
    }

    filteredCandyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
}


#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    // Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Search Button



@end
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? As it is, it's really difficult to understand what you're asking. Try shortening your example to just the code necessary to describe your problem.

Comment: The problem is that i need to add sort of packed data inside a table view cell until the user taps on the cell then i need the information from the table view cell to transfer to uitext fields.

Comment: Yep, I got that much. Your code doesn't serve to explain where this needs to happen or what data it is. Are you using a custom class? Grabbing the properties like you do with `NSString *destinationTitle = ...`? What?

Comment: To be honest I dont even know how to start with this but i believe that this info "[Candy candyOfCategory:@"Good" name:@"Bath Towel - Kmart"]," will serve as the data and that i need a nsstring to link to the text field. But i do not know the in- between of how to transfer the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "[Candy candyOfCategory:@"Good" name:@"Bath Towel - Kmart"]," will serve as the data and that i need a nsstring to link to the text field.

I'm going to assume that you need this in your destination (detail) view controller?

**Step 1:** Create a subclass of UIViewController that you can use as your custom view controller

**Step 2:** Declare `@property` objects in the custom VC header e.g.:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* category;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
```

(Or you could even use your custom Candy class too!)

**Step 3:** Instead of declaring the new destination view controller as `UIViewController`, declare it as `CandyDetailViewController` (or whatever name you like):

```
CandyDetailViewController *candyDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

**Step 4:** Below this where you're setting the destination title, you can now set the properties.

Your `prepareForSegue` method should now look something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"candyDetail"] ) {
        CandyDetailViewController *candyDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        Candy *candy;

        if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            candy = [filteredCandyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[filteredCandyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
        }
        else {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            candy = [filteredCandyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
        }
        candyDetailViewController.name = candy.name;
        candyDetailViewController.category = candy.category;
        [candyDetailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
    }
}
```